# Update variable column in one table based on value in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a somewhat bizarre use case.

Let's say I have a simple table `Persons`:

```
USE TestDB
Go

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID, LastName, FirstName, City) 
VALUES
(1, 'Smith', 'John', 'New York'),
(2, 'Doe', 'Jane', 'Los Angeles'),
(3, 'Sixpack', 'Joe', 'Chicago')
```

I also have an `Overrides` table that specifies how this table needs to be changed:

```
CREATE TABLE Overrides (
    PersonID int,
    ColumnName varchar(255),
    OverrideValue varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO Overrides (PersonID, ColumnName, OverrideValue)
VALUES
(2, 'City', 'CHANGED CITY'),
(1, 'FirstName', 'CHANGED FIRSTNAME'),
(3, 'LastName', 'CHANGED LASTNAME')
```

- `PersonID` specifies a unique row
- `ColumnName` tells me which column of that row needs to be modified
- `OverrideValue` tells me what value should be put in that row

I would like to create a process that will apply the overrides in the `Overrides` table to the `Persons` table. In the above case, `Persons` would go from its original state:

```
PersonID        LastName        FirstName       City
-----------     -----------     -----------     -----------
1               Smith           John            New York
2               Doe             Jane            Los Angeles
3               Sixpack         Joe             Chicago
```

To the following state:

```
PersonID        LastName         FirstName         City
-----------     -----------      -----------       -----------
1               Smith            CHANGED FIRSTNAME New York
2               Doe              Jane              CHANGED CITY
3               CHANGED LASTNAME Joe               Chicago
```

I could do a very ugly loop through the `Overrides` table and `UPDATE` based on each row, but I was hoping to find a more elegant approach for this non-elegant situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated.  If you don't have too many columns, then multiple `left join`s might be the simplest solution:

```
update p
    set firstname = coalesce(ofn.overridevalue, p.firstname),
        lastname = coalesce(ofn.overridevalue, p.lastname),
        city = coalesce(ofn.overridevalue, p.city)        
from persons p left join
     overrides ofn
     on p.personid = ofn.person_id and ofn.columnname = 'firstname' left join
     overrides oln
     on p.personid = oln.person_id and oln.columnname = 'lastname' left join
     overrides oc
     on p.personid = c.person_id and oc.columnname = 'city' 
where ofn.personid is not null or oln.personid is not null or oc.personid is not null;
```

If you have a lot of columns, then pre-aggregation is probably the best solution:

```
update p
    set firstname = coalesce(ofn.firstname, p.firstname),
        lastname = coalesce(ofn.lastname, p.lastname),
        city = coalesce(ofn.city, p.city)        
from persons p left join
     (select o.personid,
             max(case when columnname = 'firstname' then overridevalue end) as firstname,
             max(case when columnname = 'lastname' then overridevalue end) as lastname,
             max(case when columnname = 'city' then overridevalue end) as city
     from overrides o
     group by o.personid
    ) o
    on o.personid = p.personid;
```

Comment: There are indeed cases where several overrides in the `Overrides` table could apply to the same row in the `Persons` table, and the `Persons` table in my use case has 50+ columns. But your second suggestion looks like it will handle this very nicely!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following `UPDATE ... JOIN ...` syntax:

```
update p
set 
    p.lastName  = case when o.columnName = 'LastName'  then o.overrideValue else p.lastName end,
    p.firstName = case when o.columnName = 'FirstName' then o.overrideValue else p.firstName end,
    p.city      = case when o.columnName = 'City'      then o.overrideValue else p.city end
from persons p 
inner join overrides o on  o.personID = p.personID
```

This works by joining the two tables on `personID`, and then using a `case` expression to update the proper column; for each joined record, only one of the 3 conditional assignment will happen.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb5bf651b11579ec6e786e661b1354c0)**:

```
PersonID | LastName         | FirstName         | City        
-------: | :--------------- | :---------------- | :-----------
       1 | Smith            | CHANGED FIRSTNAME | New York    
       2 | Doe              | Jane              | CHANGED CITY
       3 | CHANGED LASTNAME | Joe               | Chicago
```

Comment: Thank you--this indeed works. Do you think this is still the best approach in a much bigger table (50+ columns)?

Comment: @brianpck . . . This will not work if you have multiple overrides for the same person.

Comment: Exactly, better done with INNER JOIN. @Gordon Linoff, what should be the behaviour in case of multiple overrides? There should be rules to apply in that case.

Comment: @davidc2p . . . An arbitrary matching row will be updated.  This is buried in the documentation for `update`.